# Blank page in mailings with notice

Tags: joomla, mailing

I'm using locally Civicrm 4.7.25 on Joomla 3.8.1 and starting from 4.7.22 (although I am not sure it's a consequence of an update) whenever I try to access a "New mailing" menu I get a blank page: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0706dy7a64
and this notice:
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Web/civi917/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Info.php on line 82
Now I don't know how to solve this issue, anyone can help me please?

Other useful info:
phpversion: 5.6.31
dbversion: 5.5.57-MariaDB
server: Apache on linux

Comment: I should add I also migrated to another linux platform, and tried switching php version (5.5, 7.0.7...), but the best I can get is a "Initializing..." on the page, under title, nothing better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure what exactly cause an "Undefined offset" PHP notice (need to go deeper), yet temporary fast emergency fix for "New Mailing" screen to appear would be PHP Notices disable via Joomla configuration

```
 /administrator/index.php?option=com_config 
 Server > Error Reporting > put it None (or Simple)
```

It seems printed notices interfere to Angular2 which tries to read page content but fails at first 
 tag of the Notice text.

Would be nice to tell Angular to pass PHP Notices texts somehow and try to figure out what happens at **Mailing/Info.php on line 82** though.

Comment: "Instant" fix for "Undefined offset": seems it fires when there is no reports in a system, so let us perform a simple empty check:      if(!empty($result['values'])) {
       $reportIds[$report] = $result['values'][0]['id'];
      }

Comment: well, it works both ways, it would be nice to get this fix accepted to the core of Civicrm (disabling php notices is not very elegant nor future proof), is there a way to accelerate the process?

Comment: You may want to follow this pull request https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11181

Answer (score 0):

This 'sounds' like the angular issue hitting your site and you are likely to find similar tickets if you search [Tags = Angular](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular)

Comment: Hi, I've delved into all the angular tagged posts, doing checks and tests, and I discovered that my Administer > System Settings > Directories page is blank (or similar), looks like:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0016dzgced

Comment: Then I went directly into civicrm_settings to test new paths, but they didn't change the situation.
Now I suspect it could be something left of the first migration from the test site, I made a search and found some records, corrected them, but the situation is the same, even after clearing all caches. Now I don't know what to do, have you got any hint (or links) for such a situation?